# How is it possible to get the input parameters of a method by having just a generic delegate?

Tags: c#, reflection

```
string CreateCacheKey(delegate methodDelegate)
{
 // return cache key based on the input parameters of the method passed to this
}

User[] GetAll(short id, string name)
{
  CreateCacheKey (this.GetAll);
}
```

How is it possible to get the input parameters of a method by having just a generic delegate?

I think the only option should be reflection.

Thanks,

Comment: The delegate type will have to be specified somewhere of course - and you probably mean the `Delegate` type rather than the `delegate` keyword (case is important here)

Answer (score 1):

A delegate has a .Method (assuming it is a single delegate, not composite - you may need to call GetInvocationList).

From the method you can query GetParameters().

Comment: this sounds to be what I'd need. how to get the GetParameters() method from a Delegate instance?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a regular `delegate`, could you specify a `delegate` with fixed parameters, or use a generic delegate type (`GetAllHandler<T>`)?

Could you explain a little more about what `CreateCacheKey` is doing and why?  Perhaps a real-world example?

Comment: the parameters are different per Repository Method. I'm using this to create cache key for my repository methods which return data from stored procedures. then storing the result in the cache or checking against existing data in the cache.

Comment: Ah, I see.  It's probably better to have each method specify how it should be cached, perhaps?  What if some of the parameters are not actually filter parameters/selection parameters and shouldn't be included in the cache key?  Or, you could use a custom attribute on the method or parameters to indicate which are part of a cache key.

Comment: custom attribute would be ideal but requires the use of an AOP like Postsharp that I can't use. in my case, all input parameters are for the query and they are all data access repository methods.